# using select in @recipients in sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail

I am using a sp_send_dbmail in a procedure. I execute it 4 times with different countries.

```
exec pr_drop_out_addresses @country='NO'
exec pr_drop_out_addresses @country='SE'
exec pr_drop_out_addresses @country='FI'
exec pr_drop_out_addresses @country='DK'
```

For each exec I would like to send the mail to set og receipients. They are different for each country. I try to solve it with a declare @recipients, but I get problems with the quotes. The code is like this. Any suggestions how to bypass the problem?

```
declare @country varchar (10)
set @country='SE'


declare @recipients nvarchar(500)='''' +select CASE when @country='NO' then 'xxxx@xxx' when @country='SE' then 'yyy@xxxx' END+'''';                                 
declare @subject nvarchar(255) = 'Adresser fra ' + @country;
declare @query_attachment_filename nvarchar(255) = 'Adresser_for_'+@country +'_'+convert(varchar(10),getdate(),121) +'.csv';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'VNPSQL email',
    @recipients = @recipients,
    @query = 'SELECT * FROM NSGstatistikk_dev.dbo.test',
    @subject = @subject,
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_attachment_filename = @query_attachment_filename,
    @query_result_separator = ';',
    @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax:
Use:

```
SELECT @recipients ='''' + CASE when @country='NO' then 'xxxx@xxx' when @country='SE' then 'yyy@xxxx' END+'''';
```

also, quotes are not required at all:

```
SELECT @recipients = CASE when @country='NO' then 'xxxx@xxx' when @country='SE' then 'yyy@xxxx' END;
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I din not know you could do it without qoutes.